# Automatizar Tareas Django

Tags: django, jobs

deseo que cada cierto tiempo django automaticamente realize cierta tarea, esta consiste en armar un archivo xml, y enviar a un webservices para que sea aprobado el mismo y retorne una respuesta y esta almacenarla.
Bien los datos los armo ya consumo el servicio, pero el problema es como hago que este proceso sea automatico y cada cierto tiempo.

```
buf = StringIO()
buf.write(documento_firmado)
buffer_xml = base64.encodestring(buf.getvalue())
# RECEPCION SRI TEST
client = Client(str(WS_RECEPCION))
result = client.service.validarComprobante(buffer_xml)
print result
if result.estado == 'RECIBIDA':
    #grabar datos Autorizacion sri
    retencion = Retencion.objects.filter(secuencia_id=secuencia).update(
        clave_autorizacion = str(clave_acceso),
        estado = 2
    )
    estado_recibido = 'ok_xml'
else:
    estado_recibido = 'no_ok'
```

Esa seria la tarea que deseo que realize cada cierto tiempo, pero desde ya nose por donde empezar agradezco cualquier sugerencia.

Comment: ¿Has investigado django-celery-beat para las tareas periódicas?

Comment: @fedorqui gracias lo voy a consultar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo en mi proyecto estoy utilizando un pluging llamado **django-cron**.

Basicamente este pluging se basa en que crear una tarea y puedes decirle que se ejecute cada X minutos o a una hora en concreto.

También puedes forzar la ejecución de los crons desde el manage para que comprobar si se está ejecutando correctamente.

### Ejemplo

```
from django_cron import CronJobBase, Schedule

class MyCronJob(CronJobBase):
    RUN_EVERY_MINS = 120 # every 2 hours

    schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=RUN_EVERY_MINS)
    code = 'my_app.my_cron_job'    # a unique code

    def do(self):
        pass    # do your thing here
```

Te dejo la documentación [aquí](https://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)